# Angular remove # from URL

Tags: angular, typescript, url, jboss, angular-routing

I'm using `{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},` in my `app.module.ts` to remove hash from the URL `localhost:4200/#/search`.
It worked fine in my local. The URL has changed to `localhost:4200/search`. It worked fine when I reload the page.

I used `ng build -op="app" --base -href="dist"` to build the application and placed those files inside `WebContent` folder in my `Maven Project`.

I have deployed the application as `ROOT.war` into JBoss. My URL has no hash `IP/search`, but when I reload the page I'm getting an `404 page not found error`.

Any solution?

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml While there is nothing specific to JBoss, the general problem is covered